# WPF: Hotkey on Button does not appear underlined when pressing ALT-Key

Tags: wpf, button, keyboard-shortcuts, hotkeys

I have a WPF application where a button is defined through

```
     <Button Command="{Binding ShowSomeDialog}">
        <AccessText>_Push me</AccessText>
     </Button>
```

The button does not show the "P" underlined when pressing the ALT-Key,  but pressing ALT-P does invoke the command.

In the same application in another window the exact same tag behaves as expected, meaning: it underlines the P when ALT-Key is pressed.

In the context where the HotKey is **not** underlined, the button is nested deeply. Simplified the hierarchy may be sketched as

1. `Window`
2. `syncfusion:TabControlExt`
3. `syncfusion:TabItemExt`
4. `UserControl`
5. `syncfusion:TabControlExt`
6. `syncfusion:TabItemExt`
7. `UserControl`
8. `Button`

The HotKey **will be** underlined if a button is added to the '4. `UserControl`' and **will not be** underlined when added to '7. `UserControl`' or deeper.

I can't find any custom styles for the elements inbetween, especially none in which the `RecognizesAccessKey` is set to `False`.

Does anyone have an idea what or where to check?

Comment: Is this button inside of any other containers?

Comment: Yes it is. It is infact deeply nested in den MDI Container which contains Tabs and each Tab contains a UserControl which contains the button. You mean it could be some 'focus'-related issue?

Comment: Containers have a `RecognizesAccessKey` attribute which disables the access key functionality, check your hierarchy and make sure that is enabled.

Comment: Thanks for the direction. Still I was unable to resolve the issue. Every ContentPresenter used has `RecognizesAccessKey` set to `True`. I detailed the question with additional information though. Maybe that helps.

Answer (score 0):

Check if you have Button restyled somewhere - access key behavior can be easily broken with incorrect style.

And btw, you did try setting Content attribute to "_Push me" directly, without using AccessText, didn't you?

P.S. [MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.accesstext(v=vs.110).aspx) may be of help here.

Comment: The restyled button was my first idea, too. I though I would have temporarily removed every custom style and it still did not work. I guess I will dive into that again. For the directly setting the Content attribute: yes, I tried that with no luck.

Comment: I recall some focus related issues using nonstandard tab control (telerik). Can you try adding a textblock and a button to tab page, make former focused and then press ALT? Something in FocusManager i think.

Answer (score 0):

Play with `<AccessText ... Margin="0,0,0,X"/>` where X is a double value and look if the underscore appears.

Comment: Sorry, that didn't help. I get your idea, though. Thanks for that.